# Transfer a file, then inline it without Webpack bundling/loader code

Tags: javascript, webpack, inline, html-webpack-plugin

I cannot come up with a working solution. I guess I should somehow be using html-webpack-inline-source-plugin or a combination of multiple entry points but this is too much for me to handle.

What I want to have is:

- all my js files bundled together and injected (not inlined) into index.html [this works of course!]
- one js file, which is not included in the bundle described above, inlined into index.html
- the inlined js file has to go through the Webpack "transformation pipe" since that js file depends on the Webpack build step

Example of the file to be inlined:

```
const asset = "require('./assets/blob.json')";
fetch(asset).then(.......)
```

This file should **first** go through the Webpack transformation since what should actually be inlined is something like:

```
<script>    
  var asset = "/static/json/blob.md5hashofblobjson.json";
  fetch(asset).then(.......)
</script>
```

So basically the file that is to be inlined ***depends on the Webpack build process*** and cannot be just read with the fs module and written directly into index.html by hand.

Also, the inlined JavaScript should ***not include*** any WebpackJSONP bundle loading code, just the pure JS. Below that inlined piece of JS should come the usual bundled scripts that are injected (not inlined).

How should I configure my build process? Thanks a mil!

Comment: Hi @pate were you able to solve this problem?  We're running into a similar situation.

Comment: @JoeM unfortunately not :/